# Hibernate Unable to find a default provider

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, bean-validation

Getting error :

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:219)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:126)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1744)


Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:208)
... 207 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to build the default ValidatorFactory
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:524)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:119)
    ... 212 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:521)
```

Hibernate related maven conf:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.5.SP1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions> 
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions> 
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.9</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Suggestions that I found were:

1. Use hibernate 4+
2. User hibernate validation 4+
3. Add hibernate validation libraries
4. Add jsr305 (imo doesnt really matter)
5. Add javax validation libraries
6. Add hibernate-validator-annotation-processor

I have those all, but still getting error.

EDIT:

Showing how I am using my hibernate.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">5</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>


        <mapping class="com.foo.bar.MyClass />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Building:

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();

        configuration.setNamingStrategy(ImprovedNamingStrategy.INSTANCE); // also other configuration changes made here

        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();

        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry); // this line gives the error


    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        log.error("Initial SessionFactory creation failed.", ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar as well?... if yes then remove it.

Comment: I removed that library, which was in my POM, still same issue though...

Comment: K just a thought try changing hibernate-validator to 4.1.0 ?

Comment: @DanglingPiyush same problem, but weird is that, when maven is building, it is doing this: `[INFO] Copying validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar to \target\classes\META-INF\lib\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar` . I am not sure why, though.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your 6 points:

- Use hibernate 4+
- User hibernate validation 4+

Hibernate Validator 4.x is reference implementation of Bean Validation. And that's the right version to use. It is integrated in Hibernate 4. So versions seem right

- Add hibernate validation libraries

Yes, that's required and you do that by adding the *hibernate-validator* dependency.

- Add jsr305 (imo doesnt really matter)

Not related. Not even sure what JSR that is.

- Add javax validation libraries

You do that explicitly, but they are also a transitive dependency to *hibernate-validator* so you would get them either way.

- Add hibernate-validator-annotation-processor

No, that not required/related

So why does it not work? I think to answer this question we need more information. The exception suggests that *javax.validation.Validation* cannot see/load the Hibernate Validator Bean Validation provider. Do you work in a constrained class laoding environment? How do you use all these dependencies?

Comment: I made edit to my first post, where it shows how I am initializing hibernate(using dependencies).

Comment: But where do you run the code? In a Java SE application? Web application? EAR? Which container are you using?

Comment: Visibility should not be an issue in this case. Can you outline the content of the webapp as it is deployed? Which jars are in the lib directory etc